# Unable to Install any packages in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have Windows 10. My goal is to set up Virtual Environment and then install modules (**django** for example) to it.

My steps:

1. Tried: **python -m venv env**. Got the Error:

   Error: Command '['C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Django - Web Development\env\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
2. Then tried: **pip install virtualenv** and **virtualenv env**. Virtual Environment successfully created.
3. Activated Virtual Environment: **env\Scripts\activate**
4. Tried: **pip install django**. Got the Error:

   Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Django - Web Development\env\Scripts\pip.exe" install django'
5. Tried: **where python**

   C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Django - Web Development\env\Scripts\python.exe

   C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
6. Tried: **where pip**

   C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Django - Web Development\env\Scripts\pip.exe

   C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe
7. Confirmed: Python PATH C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\ added to Environment Variables.
8. Deactivated Virtual Environment: **deactivate**
9. Tried: **pip install django**. No error, Django installed successfully.

Comment: This may just be paranoia against files and folders with spaces in them, but have you tried using a path that doesn't have spaces in it?

Comment: Try upgrading pip in the env ```python -m pip install --upgrade pip```. Also, if you are on Mac then you should use ```python3```.

Comment: @jjoa, I get an error when try to update Pip: Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip'